# Grails / Hibernate with MS Sql Server 2008 - any issues?

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008, grails, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been working with a project which is using grails / hibernate with MySql db... Now I want to switch the project with grails / hibernate with MS Sql Server 2008...

So, for that I would like to know that is there any compatibility issues anybody have faced so far ?

I got the database ready using SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for MySql... Now If I want to test it with existing grails/hibernate project then what are the changes I need to apply with the hibernate configuration file ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues. Grails is compiled to Java which interacts with hibernate which interacts with JDBC which interacts with the SQL Server. I've been using this whole stack (apart grails) for years in production without a problem. A switch to database is as simple as switching the hibernate dialect. The semantics to MySQL are almost the same (auto increment instead of sequences).

Comment: I'm getting issue in reconnecting database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027576/grails-3-automatic-reconnect-with-ms-sql-server