# Grails 3 Automatic Reconnect with MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, grails, grails-3.0

I am developing a web application on Grails 3.2.2 with spring boot and hibernate and MS SQL Server as a backend database. I want my application to reconnect with the database automatically whenever SQL server comes back after a restart or any other issue.

This is how my ***application.yml*** file database-related properties look like:

```
development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://machine_host_name:1433/db_name?autoReconnect=true
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

And this is the JTDS library, I'm using in ***build.gradle*** file:

```
compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'
```

So, with these configurations too, my application is unable to reconnect to the MS SQL Server automatically after the restart of SQL Server service.

Comment: As far as I can tell, GORM doesn't _directly_ support dynamic database connections.  There are some words in the multi-tenancy section of the docs that discuss it (http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#_adding_tenants_at_runtime)

Comment: I use both MySQL and Oracle and can confirm GORM is able to reconnect after failed db just fine. You're settings look good. I noticed this is for development not sure if you meant it for production (i.e. war deployment). Also you have to make sure your validationQuery works correctly for your database. Does select 1 work for ms sql? In Oracle you use select 1 from dual.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue when using the Javamelody plugin, compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-melody-plugin:1.72.0' in build.gradle.

Once I commented this out it resolved reconnection issues to our database. May not be the same issue for you but perhaps for others it maybe.